# How to upload file into project folder and get its name using multer and Node.js

Tags: node.js, multer

I need to save file into folder and want to get that file's name to save into database using Node.js.

api.js:

```
 var multer  = require('multer')
    var storage =multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './../uploads');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
      }
    });
    exports.saveCardDetails=function(upload.single('image'),req,res){
    var name=req.body.name;
    var company=req.body.company;
    var position=req.body.position;
    var mobile=req.body.mobile;
    var email=req.body.email;
    var landline=req.body.landline;
    var url=req.body.url;
    var postcode=req.body.postcode;
    var address=req.body.address;
    var image=req.body.image;
    var userid=req.body.userid;
    var profiletext=req.body.profile;
    var biography=req.body.biography;
    var token_id=req.body.token_id;
    console.log('request',req);
}
```

server.js:

```
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var session = require('express-session');
var app=module.exports=express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var port=8989;
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
var api=require('./api/api.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.post('/api/users/save-card-details',api.saveCardDetails);
```

After this I am getting the following error:

```
POST /api/users/save-card-details 413 13.277 ms - 1120
Error: request entity too large
    at readStream (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:196:17)
    at getRawBody (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12)
    at read (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:76:3)
    at urlencodedParser (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:115:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at logger (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
```

Here I am getting the image and need to save into folder. After saving into folder I need saved file name into `exports.saveCardDetails` function. My folder structure is given below.

```
--> api/api.js

--> upload
```

I am using `multer` npm package for this.

Comment: have you tried some code ? What was output ? You read multer usage ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like multer is failing for large file size.

Try setting the fieldSize variable in multer config like this -

```
multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: maxSize }
 })
```

You can find these settings here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer (search for limit).
Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually i am posting data from `postman -form-data` and getting much binary unreadble value in server side.

Comment: here `console.log('request',req);` I am getting much unreadble data.

Comment: And `fileSize` infinity in default.

Comment: u should not log req like that, try logging req.file and req.body. what is key name in postman request?

Comment: I have also tried like that `(i.e-console.log('request',req.body))` same binary data are coming. Actually I have set header as `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and using `form-data` in postman.I have posted all key name of postman like `for  var name=req.body.name` the key is name.

Comment: @satya you found any solution ?